# Search and replace with regular expression

Tags: html, regex, text-editor

Iam trying to search and replace with regular expression, but it is not working.

I have some html like so:

```
<p><b>Noten</b></p>
<p><b>somethingelse</b></p>
<p><b>random extra</b></p>
<p><b>something 3</b></p>
```

And want it like so:

```
<h2>Noten</h2>
<h2>somethingelse</h2>
<h2>random extra</h2>
<h2>something 3</h2>
```

But it how do i find all the right elements?
I only can find the ones without the spaces or numbers, like so:

```
<p><b>[a-z]*</b></p>
```

and i don't know how to replace it so that the `<p>` and `<b>` tags change in `<h2>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Test It

```
var regex = /<p><b>([^>]+)<\/b><\/p>/ig;
var s="<p><b>Noten</b></p>";
var result = s.replace(regex, "<h2>$1<\/h2>");
alert(result);
```

but I Recommend you to Use Dom and JQuery for do This It is more easier

Answer (score 2):

try this

it is in javascript

```
s="<p><b>Noten</b></p>"
s.replace("<p><b>","<h2>")
s.replace("</p></b>","</h2>")
```

Working example:

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZqqFv/2/

Answer (score 1):

A lot depends on where you trying to use the regular expression, but i would just simply run it one for

```
<p><b>

/<p><b>/<h2>/
```

and the second time

```
<\/b><\/p>

/<\/b><\/p>/<\/h2>/
```